# Can I take upwork projects outside of the website?

Tags: halal-haram

I've registered myself on Upwork to land opportunities. Now when I don't have "connects" (points to apply for the job) I do this process which I want to ask. Please read below.

See If someone wants to hire they post a job. Now what I do when I see any job there I don't apply to the job directly.

- I scroll down and take their location.
- In past review/Feedback section I try to find their names.
- If got I search them on LinkedIn and contact them to work with me.

Is it jayaz? Permissable.